# What game engine does Mega Jump use?

Tags: iphone

What game engine does the iphone game Mega Jump use? Im guessing it's unity 3d but it could be anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cocos2D, judging by their development blog.

http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/21/cocos2d-and-uiscrollview/